# Can't access object property in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, ecmascript-6

I've struggled for a while seek for help. This is really strange. I want to access an object property, but this always throws an error:

> TypeError : cannot read property template of undefined

But my application works properly. Just there is notification output if can't access template of undefined

```js
//this is my object variabel 
var login = {};

login.data = {
    checkInput : formValidation,
    userSchema : User,
    template   : 'pages/users/login',
}


// so I add new method which I call in different files 
login.header = async(req, res, next) => { 
  /// in this section function I want to read property of template but it always return undefined 
  
  try {
    //  I have some code with read databases here 

    //some data i want to render 
    var data = {};
    res.render(this.data.template,data);
    
    // I've been also trying another way.
    var template = login.data.template !== undefined ?  'page/users/login' : login.data.template;
    
    res.render(login.data.template, data);
    
    // both of above always return output, but can't read template of undefined
    
  } catch(e) {
  
    throw new Error(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, why call `res.render()` twice?  Can only send one response per request.

Comment: it's just for another way i use. yes i use one by one dude. just for make example if i use two way trying this error

Comment: Don't add code "as example". Show code _that actually goes wrong_ (ideally, as [mcve]). Showing two renders is a guaranteed problem, so if you don't use that in your actual code, don't show it in your example code either.

Comment: Well, this is non-functional and wrong demo code.  Show your REAL code if you want the best chance of getting good help.

Comment: look at bottom dude. i've explained realy clear.. huhuhu.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using an arrow function which loses the binding to `login` (the `this` you're accessing is an attempt to access the `login` object). Use a regular ES5 function.

```
login.header = async function(req, res, next) {...};
```

As found in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

> An **arrow function expression** is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function), although without its own bindings to the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), [`super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super), or [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) keywords. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.

Comment: wait dude. arrow function deleted property this, but i still can't  access with **login.data.template ** ??? it still throw me typeError

Answer (score 0):

i've been trying to access with property with no array function

```js
var login = {}
login.data = {
  template : 'admin/pages/'
  body : {}
};

login.getViews = function(req, res, next) {
  // it'l throw an error 
  res.render(this.data.template, this.data.body);
   
  // than i try with another way, it works 
    res.render(login.data.template, login.data.body);
 
    
}
```

so why i could't access with property this even i use no rows function??